# Endomorphism $f$ of finitely generated R-module M such that $f(M)\in IM$ satisfies an equation of the form $f^n+a_1f^{n-1}+...+a_n=0$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let M be a non-zero finitely generated R module, where R is a commutative ring with unity, Let I be an ideal of R, and f be an R-module endomorphism of M such that $f(M) \subseteq IM$. Then f satisfies an equation of the form
$$f^n+a_1f^{n-1}+...+a_n=O$$ where $a_i's$ are in R.

Proof

Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ be the generators of M, because $f(M) \subseteq IM$, so

$f(x_1)=a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n$

$f(x_2)=a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+...+a_{2n}x_n$

$...$

$f(x_n)=a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+...+a_{nn}x_n$

$\implies$
$\begin{bmatrix} a_{11}-f & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}-f& ... &a_{2n}\\ ... &...&...&... \\a_{n1}& a_{n2} &...&a_{nn}-f
\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\.\\x_n
\end{bmatrix}$
$=$
$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\.\\0
\end{bmatrix}$

$\implies$ determinant of the coefficient matrix is zero as above system has a non zero solution, which will give an equation of the required form.

$\textbf{Question}$

I am new to commutative algebra, I just want know if my approach is right or lacks something.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have a matrix $M$ with entries in the ring commutative ring $R[f]$, and $M \cdot x = 0$. Multiply on the left by the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $M$, and get $(\det M \cdot I_n) \cdot x = 0$.